# TSQL - Convert string yyyy/day number to date

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, type-conversion

In T-SQL, I am trying to convert the following varchar into a date so I can see if that date is 90 or 180 days prior to today.

```
YYYY/(Day of the year)
```

For example: 2016/53 would be 2/22/2016.

If I ran this...

```
SELECT
[DAY] as 'YR/DAY'
,left([Day],4) as Year
,right([Day],LEN([Day])-CHARINDEX('/',[Day])) as Day
FROM 
DATE_TABLE
```

I would get this...

```
YR/DAY    Year  Day
2016/53   2016  53
```

I would like to get this...

```
YR/DAY    Year  Day  Date
2016/53   2016  53   2/22/2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
DATEADD(DAY, [day] - 1, CAST([year] AS CHAR(4)) + '-01-01')
```

Added a missing ')'